# Counting the number of points inside a circle of my scatter plot

Tags: python, count, scatter-plot

I need to count how many points of my scatter plot are inside the black circle. Here is what I have but my sum of points is 0 (clearly wrong).

I have plotted a circle on top of my scatter plot and  iterate over the list of points and use the matplotlib.path.Path.contains_point() method to check whether each point is inside the circle.

```py
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.path import Path

plt.scatter(headX, headY)

circle = Circle((130, 150), radius=70, color ='black', fill =False)
plt.gca().add_patch(circle)

circle_path = circle.get_path()

point_count = 0

for xx, yy in zip(headX, headY):
    if circle_path.contains_point((xx, yy)):
        point_count += 1
        
print(f"{point_count} points found inside the circle.")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a circle centered at `(x, y)` with a radius of `r`.

A point `(px, py)` is inside this circle if its [distance from the center of the circle](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html) is less than the radius.

```
point_count = 0
for px, py in zip(headX, headY):
    if (px-x)**2 + (py-y)**2 <= r**2:
        point_count += 1
```

Or, we could use the fact that `True` is considered as `1`, and `False` as `0` to condense this to a one-liner like so:

```
point_count = sum((px-x)**2 + (py-y)**2 <= r**2 for px, py in zip(headX, headY))
```